# Using facebook app both as fb connect to my site and also as app on facebook?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm using **facebook connect** on my website, now I want to develop an app on my facebook page that will require the users to do a facebook login to my website and then answer a quick trivia.
my questions:

1. can I use 1 app for both platforms?
2. can I let the user to do a facebook connect on my website from the
   facebook app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. But keep in mind that the **maximum width allowed in a Page Tab is 810px**.

2) Yes. Use the Javascript Api.